# Prove that there's only one matrix which is involutory and idempotent at the same time.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

An *involutory* matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is such that $\mathbf{A}^{2}=\mathbf{I}$.

An *idempotent* matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is such that $\mathbf{A}^{2}=\mathbf{A}$

So we'd have to satisfy both conditions simultaneously.

I do know the answer to the question is the identity matrix itself. But how can we go about proving it?

One way I thought of is to expose that the diagonal of $\mathbf{A}^{2}$ and condition that all other entries must be zero, but then I would already be biased by knowing the answer beforehand.

It'd be really nice if you guys gave me a hand with this one. In the meantime I'll carry on trying.

Comment: $A^2=A$ and $A^2=I$. Doesn't this naturally mean $A=I=A^2$?

Comment: $A=A^2=I\implies A= I$

Comment: I think you meant *involutory*

Comment: Thanks for that @J.W.Tanner. Indeed, Rohit, it would. Yet I am trying to give a more detailed demonstration.  Since the $\mathbf{A}^{2}$ yields $a_{ii}^{2}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and that would have to be $1$. Now, as for $a_i * a_j$ for every $i \neq j$ the answer should be zero. Therefore mounting to an identity matrix. Yet it feels like I'd be missing something with such arguments. Hence the post.

Comment: @upStoneLock: You know that $A=A^{2}=I,$ so you're done. If you are looking for more than this, then it is unclear what you are asking. Could you clarify what more you want?

Answer (score -1):

For idempotent  matrix $A^2 = A$, it means the polynomial  $p(x) = x^2 - x = x(x-1)$ is satisfied by matrix  $A$. Hence its possible  options  for minimal polynomial  for $A$ are $x$ , $(x-1)$ and $x(x-1)$. While for an involutary  matrix $A^2 = I$ . So polynomial  $q(x) = x^2 -1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ is satisfied  by matrix A. So  the  possible  cases for minimal polynomial   are : (x-1), $(x+1)$ and $(x-1)(x+1)$. So when the matrix is both idempotent  and involutary the only possible  common option  for minimal polynomial  is : m(x) = (x-1). Since any matrix satisfies  its  minimal polynomial , we get  A - I = O, the zero matrix. Hence  $A = I$, the identity  matrix .